# SQL Server services not running on startup

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have a machine that no matter what when installing SQL Server 2014 Express, I get the following error installing:

> Action required:
>   Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
>
> Feature failure reason:
>   An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
>
> Error details:
>   § Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   Error code: 0x84BB0001
>
> Product Update:
>   Product Update has successfully applied KB 3058865 http://support.microsoft.com/?id=3058865. These updates have set the patch level of the Setup operation to 12.1.4100.0.

I have totally removed SQL Server from the registry, raised the user to an admin, 
raised folder rights to full access in Users\default and in all users concerned with SQL Server.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are installing SQL Server? The error says, it was SP1 and not Database Engine